# Adding `Xamarin.AndroidX.Biometric` in .NET MAUI Library throws an exception

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, maui

When I add Xamarin.AndroidX.Biometric to a Maui class library and then try to use this library in my project it starts throwing the below error. Any clues on what could be causing this?

You can checkout this [Github](https://github.com/FreakyAli/Plugin.Maui.Biometric/tree/r1-gh/feat/biometric-setup-android-ios) as a reproduction repo.

For the time being I have raised an issue with MAUI but I am not sure if this is really a bug with MAUI or am I missing something https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/20315

```
/Users/gulamalihakim/Documents/Personal/Plugin.Maui.Biometric/Plugin.Maui.Biometric/Samples: Error JAVA0000: Error in /Users/gulamalihakim/.nuget/packages/xamarin.androidx.collection.jvm/1.3.0.2/buildTransitive/net7.0-android33.0/../../jar/androidx.collection.collection-jvm.jar:androidx/collection/ArraySetKt.class:
Type androidx.collection.ArraySetKt is defined multiple times: /Users/gulamalihakim/.nuget/packages/xamarin.androidx.collection.jvm/1.3.0.2/buildTransitive/net7.0-android33.0/../../jar/androidx.collection.collection-jvm.jar:androidx/collection/ArraySetKt.class, /Users/gulamalihakim/.nuget/packages/xamarin.androidx.collection.ktx/1.2.0.9/buildTransitive/net6.0-android31.0/../../jar/androidx.collection.collection-ktx.jar:androidx/collection/ArraySetKt.class
Compilation failed
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete, origin: /Users/gulamalihakim/.nuget/packages/xamarin.androidx.collection.jvm/1.3.0.2/buildTransitive/net7.0-android33.0/../../jar/androidx.collection.collection-jvm.jar
androidx/collection/ArraySetKt.class
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.R0.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:126)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.main(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:5)
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete, origin: /Users/gulamalihakim/.nuget/packages/xamarin.androidx.collection.jvm/1.3.0.2/buildTransitive/net7.0-android33.0/../../jar/androidx.collection.collection-jvm.jar:androidx/collection/ArraySetKt.class
    at Version.fakeStackEntry(Version_8.1.56.java:0)
    at com.android.tools.r8.M.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:5)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.R0.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:81)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.R0.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:32)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.R0.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:31)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.R0.b(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:2)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:26)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.b(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:13)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:24)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.R0.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:113)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.b: Type androidx.collection.ArraySetKt is defined multiple times: /Users/gulamalihakim/.nuget/packages/xamarin.androidx.collection.jvm/1.3.0.2/buildTransitive/net7.0-android33.0/../../jar/androidx.collection.collection-jvm.jar:androidx/collection/ArraySetKt.class, /Users/gulamalihakim/.nuget/packages/xamarin.androidx.collection.ktx/1.2.0.9/buildTransitive/net6.0-android31.0/../../jar/androidx.collection.collection-ktx.jar:androidx/collection/ArraySetKt.class
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.O2.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:21)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.O2.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:26)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.A2.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:44)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.A2.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:10)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.merge(ConcurrentHashMap.java:2048)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.A2.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:6)
    at com.android.tools.r8.graph.b4$a.e(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:7)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.c.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:58)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.c.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:9)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.c.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:8)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:29)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.d(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:17)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.c(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:1)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.R0.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:28)
    ... 6 more
 (JAVA0000) (Samples) java
```

Comment: Going to sound really daft, but the fact the plugin is for Xamarin and not for Maui.

Comment: @AndyDonegan We don't have anything for MAUI as of now anyway, These are not even deprecated and replaced yet and hence this is what we should be using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after spending some time with the error I realised that the issue was that the Biometric Nuget needed the latest version of `Xamarin.Androidx.Collection.Ktx` adding that to my project fixed the issue, I think this reference should be internally bounded into the NuGet itself.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.AndroidX.Collection.Ktx

Comment: We also went through this and you might find this implementation and code useful - https://github.com/oscoreio/Maui.Biometric

Comment: That's interesting I did not find this before and ended up creating my own package a couple of months ago lol https://github.com/FreakyAli/Plugin.Maui.Biometric